# How to use dodgr_isochrones with a given points object in R

Tags: r, gis, dodgr

I am trying to plot an isochrone map based on the locations of some convenience stores. Been searching on different methods (and I'm open to changing it) but for now I am working with dodgr.

```
q = opq(bbox = c(-103.78,19.2, -103.65, 19.31 )) %>% 
add_osm_feature(key = "highway")
osm_sc <- osmdata_sc(q = q)
```

I am not sure on how to share the points layer but it is a class sf

> class(kiosko_sf)
> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

```
graph_motorcar <- weight_streetnet(osm_sc, wt_profile = "motorcar")

tlim <- c (5, 10, 20, 30, 60) * 60 
x <- dodgr_isochrones (graph_motorcar, from = kiosko_sf, tlim)
```

I am pretty sure my mistake is with that layer, as I don't fully understand what type of object should be passed to the from argument. I get the following error:

> Error in get_pts_index(graph, gr_cols, vert_map, pts) : Unable to determine geographical coordinates in from/to

How could I fix this? or could you recommend an alternative to using dodgr_isochrones?

Comment: Would you share the part how you create kiosko_sf object?

Comment: I downloaded it from this site https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/mapa/denue/default.aspx and the transformed to a more suitable crs (EPSG: 4486)
`kiosko_sf <- st_read("data/shp/INEGI_DENUE_kiosko.shp", options="ENCODING=latin1")`

Comment: as `dodgr_isochrones` expects a matrix instead of `geometry`, you can convert geometry points with `st_coordinates` like `x <- dodgr_isochrones (graph, from = sf::st_coordinates(kiosko_sf$geometry), tlim)`

Comment: I ended up doing this  
`from <- kiosko_sf %>% `
`  select(longitud, latitud) %>% `
`  st_drop_geometry()`
But obviously your approach is cleaner. Now I have another problem... how to map the results?
I tried with:
`iso <-  st_as_sf(x, coords=c("x","y"))  `

`polys <-  iso %>%   
  dplyr::group_by(tlim) %>%   
  dplyr::summarise() %>%  
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%   
  st_convex_hull()`

But the hull is created with all the points taken into account so when I have very far apart points, the area in between ends up being filled also.